# Post data to current php page with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i want to post data to current page with ajax.But i couldnt do that.

I have doctor panel and i wanna get patient's data from 'hastalar' table in my db by using patient's national id:'tc'.Session is using by doctor so i guess i cant use $_SESSION for patient at same time.And i wanna use only one php page.So i cant see my patient's datas in current page.Pls help me guys.

### dokyon.php

### textbox

```
<a href="#" id="ara" class="ara" ><br/>SEARCH PATIENT</a>
<input type ="text" id="tc" name="tc" />
```

### JQUERY

```
   <script type="text/javascript" >
     $(function() { 
       $(".ara").click(function(){
        var tc = $('#tc').val();
        $.ajax({
            url:'dokyon.php'//current page
            type: 'POST',
            data:{tc:tc},
            success: function(){
                alert(data);

            }
        });
    });
  });
   </script>
```

### php codes

```
    <?php 



       $tc=$_POST['tc'];

       echo $tc;

        $query = mysqli_query($connection,"select * from hastalar where tc_no=$tc");

         while($hasta = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

         echo $hasta['name'];}

         ?>
```

Comment: This should work. What problem are you having with it?

Comment: you need to add the `data` parameter the the success handler: `success: function(data){alert(data);}`

Comment: @Barmar i am getting Notice: Undefined index: tc.... and Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ... because it doesnt post anything.... i cant echo $tc.

Comment: You need to use `if(isset($_POST['tc']))` so that the code only runs when you post to the page, not when you open the page normally.

Comment: @mpf82 i doesnt matter i cant see echo $tc; because it doesnt post.

Comment: You don't see it in the `alert()`?

Comment: `tc` is going to be a string or integer? Try `var_dump($_POST);` is the value you are sending under some other index?

Comment: @Barmar i change it to alert(tc).now i can see tc but i cant see my patients name.$_POST['tc']; isnt working.

Comment: @chris85 tc is string.No it isnt.

Comment: apart from all the debugging: You shouldn't have that all in _one_ php script. Have one script that does the ui, one that serves the data (if you wanna work with ajax). You wouldn't have all that hassle then.

Comment: @chris85 i used var_dump and it says it is empty.

Comment: @jeff really ? :( i thought i can do it....

Comment: Yes, you CAN do that. But you shouldn't. Technically it will be working. But much harder to maintain, much harder to get the right workflow, harder to debug,...

Comment: @Jeff yeah you are right.But after click search button, i wanna list all patients at current page.How can i do it?

Comment: When using ajax you (or the user) will stay on the same page. There's just another php script in the background that gives you the wanted data based on what you request from it.

Comment: reading all the instructions you've alread got, this should/could work. But as I said before, in this scenario (all in one script) it's harder to debug - especially cause you didn't show the _whole_ script. It looks like the mistake is somewhere else.

Comment: @Jeff so how can get `echo $hasta['name'];` in the current page?i can see it in other page that have `echo $hasta['name'];`

Comment: unless you show the whole script I cannot say where the misstake is.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

For your ajax code, you need to add dataType parameter and add the parameter of `success: function(data)`, so like this:

```
$.ajax({
            url:'dokyon.php'//current page
            type: 'POST',
            data:{tc:tc},
            dataType:"html",
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);

            }
        });
```

For additional: always do debuging for sending data with inspect element of browser.
Hopefully it will be success for you :)